# Convert to sql query

Tags: c#, sql

Explanation: I have a list of client objects that contains datetime lasthello and string isconnect amongst others.
I have now moved the objects to an sql table instead of a runtime list.
my question, how would I go about running through the table looking for entries where the following is present, and change it. - in a fairly optimized way (by optimized I mean fast)
the "hold" is also located in a table now and not in the settings file. and the isconnect is a bool now, and NOT a string.

```
foreach(entry in mylist)
{
    if ((DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Settings.Default.Hold)) > entry.lasthello &&
                                    entry.isConnect != "Disconnected")
                                {
                                    entry.client.Disconnect();
                                }
}
```

how do i calculated the timespan within an sql query? òr should it be done in multiple queries?

solved!

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
                {

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(DisconnectOnNoHello, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lasthello",(DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(hold))));
                    try
                    {
                        IScsServerClient client = (IScsServerClient)ByteArrayToObject((byte[]) cmd.ExecuteScalar());    
                        client.Disconnect();
                        closeConnection(conn);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Too less information. How does your table look like, what rdbms are you using?

Comment: This seems like something that should stay in memory - if your server restarts, the sessions are going to be disconnected. Don't move it to SQL.

Comment: Maybe try Linq to SQL ? Not much info in your question.

Comment: this shouldn't stay in memory the data is dynamic and is saved in an sqlDB either way, I could just create a list and use that on start, but this is a long running service, and i need to update the list on disconnect. I have solved my problem, Marc seemed to get the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, `DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Settings.Default.Hold)` doesn't seem to depend on `entry`, so you could just calculate that first and pass it in as a parameter, i.e.

```
select *
from [SomeTable]
where @foo > lasthello
and isConnect <> 'Disconnected'
```

But otherwise: `datediff`.

Comment: ofcourse I can. Thank you very much!
can't believe i didn't just see it at the get go >.<

Comment: so something along the lines of
SELECT * FROM entrytable WHERE lasthello < @lasthellodiff and isconnect = 'true'